# sed convert multiline bloc to single line (ex: fasta to phylip format)

Tags: sed, fasta

In **short**:

how to convert from fasta to "phylip"-like format (without the sequence and residu counts at the top of the file) using `sed` ?

A fasta format is like this:

```
>sequence1
AATCG
GG-AT
>sequence2
AGTCG
GGGAT
```

The number of lines of a sequence may vary.

I want to convert it to this:

```
sequence1 AATCG GG-AT
sequence2 AGTCG GGGAT
```

My question seems simple, but I am lacking a real understanding of the advanced commands in `sed`, the multiline commands and the commands using the hold buffer.

Here is the implementation idea I had:
fill the pattern space with sequence, and only print it when a new sequence label is encountered. To do this, I would:

1. Search lines matching `^>`. If found:

   - print the previous pattern space
   - append line to pattern space
2. if `^>` not found:

   - append line to pattern space

I read this great [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html),
but I am still unsure about a few things, mostly the difference between the capitalized and little letters:

- when you use P instead of p:
  does it print the *first* line of the pattern space (in file order)? 
  I am confused by the use of "up to the next newline".
- do I have to use a **loop** to read lines until the next sequence name, or are the multiline commands sufficient?
- do I have to use the hold space in this example?

*I know python, perl and awk* and I think they would be more "human-friendly" tools to achieve this, but I want to learn some advanced sed.

---

Nothing I tried worked now, but here are some pieces:

This script uses the line numbers, not trying to do pattern matching.
It shoes what I want to do, and now I need to automate it using match addresses:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
1h
2,3H
4{x; s/\n/ /g; p}
5H
6{H;x; s/\n/ /g; p}
```

`sed -nf fa2phy.sed my.fasta` returns the expected output.

Comment: it's easier and more robust to do it with Awk ... good luck with sed

Comment: also, you should probably use bio-related tools for such problems - bioperl/biopython/bioawk/etc... for ex: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-to-convert-fasta-to-bed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397672/how-to-convert-phylip-format-to-fasta

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed '/>/N;:A;/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;N;bA};h;s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p;x;s/.*\n//;bA' infile
```

Comment: Thanks, great codegolf answer ;) However, as I begin to understand, `s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p` would be equivalent to `P` and `s/.*\n//` to `D`, so we could even write `sed '/>/N;:A;/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;N;bA};h;P;x;D;bA' infile`.

Comment: And actually, from my tests, the `h` and `x` are not needed, as well as the starting `/>/N`, so it seems that the command can be stripped down to:
`sed ':A;/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;N;bA};P;D;bA' infile`

Comment: Actually, I was wrong... `P` and `D` are not equivalent to the patterns I said, because of _greedy_ matching. It works here because there are always exactly 2 lines in the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

Following simple awk could help you in same.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk '/^>/{sub(/>/,"");if(val){print val, val2};val=$0;val2="";next} {val2=val2?val2 FS $0:$0} END{print val, val2}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk -v RS=">" -v FS="\n" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"\n":" ")}}'   Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:***

```
awk -v RS=">" '{gsub(/\n/," ");} NF'   Input_file
```

Comment: you'll do it much easily by manipulating RS and re-aligning fields

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks sir, I added 2 more solutions too now(related to setting RS in code), cheers :)

Comment: no need gsub, default FS is white-space including newline and default OFS is single space... `awk -v RS='>' 'NR>1{$1=$1; print}'`

Comment: These are interesting, useful, and quite challenging lines of awk, thanks! I like the challenge of using `sed` though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I believe I managed to answer my own question.

Here is the script I made: `fa2phy.sed`:

```
#!/bin/sed -nf

:readseq
${H;b out}              # if last line, append to hold, and goto 'out'
1{h;n;b readseq}        # if first, overwrite hold, and start again at 'readseq'
/^>/!{H; n; b readseq}  # if not a sequence label, append to hold, read next line, start again at 'readseq'. Else, it continues to 'out'

:out
x;         # exchange hold content with pattern content
s/^>//;    # substitute the starting '>'
s/\n/  /g; # substitute each newline with 2 spaces
p;         # print pattern buffer
```

Although it works, if someone has a shorter or clearer solution, enlighten me! :)