# Explain this sed conditional branching behavior

Tags: sed

I have the following (gnu) `sed` script, which is intended to parse another sed script, and output distinct commands on a separate line.

In words, this script should put a newline after each semicolon `;`, except  semicolons that are inside a matching or substitution command.

**Sed script**:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

# IDEA:
# replace ';' by ';\n' except when it's inside a match expression or subst. expression.

# Ignored patterns:
/^#/b   # commented lines
/^$/b   # empty lines
# anything in a single line, without semicolon except at the end
/^[^\n;]*;?$/b

# Processed patterns (put on separate lines):
# Any match preceding a semicolon, or the end of the line, or a substitution
s_/^[^/]+/[^;s]*;?_&\n_;      t printtopline
s/^\\(.)[^\1]+\1[^;s]*;?/&\n/;t printtopline
# Any substitution (TODO)

# Any other command, separated by semicolon
s/\;/\;\n/; t printtopline;

:printtopline
P;D;  # print top line, delete it, start new cycle
```

For example, I tested it with the following file (actually adapted from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910836/4614641) of @ctac_ to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46908372/4614641) of my previous sed questions):

**Input file:**

```
#!/bin/sed -f

#/^>/N;

:A;
/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;N;bA};  # join next line if not a sequence label
#h;
#s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p;
s/^>//g;P

#x;
#s/.*\n//;
D
bA;
```

### Output

The above script produces the right output, for example, the line `/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;N;bA};  # join next line if not a sequence label` becomes:

```
/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;
N;
bA};
  # join next line if not a sequence label
```

### Question

However, could you help me understand **why this part of the script works:**

```
s/\;/\;\n/; t printtopline;

:printtopline
```

**?**

I seems to me that the branching command `t printtopline` is useless here. I thought whatever the success of the substitution, the next thing to be executed would be `:printtopline`.

However, if I comment out the `t` command, or if I replace it with `b`, the script produces the following output lines:

```
/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;
N;bA};  # join next line if not a sequence label
```

From `info sed`, here is the explanation of `t`:

> ```
> 't LABEL'
>      Branch to LABEL only if there has been a successful 's'ubstitution
>      since the last input line was read or conditional branch was taken.
>      The LABEL may be omitted, in which case the next cycle is started.
> ```

Why isn't the **`t` command immediately followed by its label** not behaving like no command at all or the `b` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crucial part is this:

> Branch to *label* only if there has been a successful substitution **since the last input line was read or conditional branch was taken**.

I.e. `t` looks into the past and takes into account the success of all recent substitutions up to the most recent

- input, or
- conditional branch.

Consider the input line you're asking about. After all the substitutions we have

```
/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;
N;bA};  # join next line if not a sequence label
```

in our pattern space when we reach `P;D;`. The `P` commands outputs the first line, then `D` deletes the first line and restarts the main loop. Now we just have

```
N;bA};  # join next line if not a sequence label
```

Note that this didn't involve reading any additional lines. No input occurred; `D` just removed parts of the pattern space.

We process the remaining text (which does nothing because none of the other patterns match) until we reach this part of the code:

```
s_/^[^/]+/[^;s]*;?_&\n_;      t printtopline
```

The substitution fails (the pattern space doesn't contain `/^`). But the `t` command doesn't check the status of just this one `s` command; it looks at the history of all substitutions since the most recent input or conditional branch taken.

The most recent input occurred when `/\n>/!{s/\n/ /;N;bA};` was read.

The most recent conditional branch taken was

```
s/\;/\;\n/; t printtopline;

:printtopline
```

in the original version of your code. Since then no other substitution succeeded, so the `t` command does nothing. The rest of the program continues as expected.

But in the modified version of your code there was no conditional branch at this point (`b` is an unconditional branch):

```
s/\;/\;\n/; b printtopline;

:printtopline
```

That means the `t` from `s_/^[^/]+/[^;s]*;?_&\n_;      t printtopline` "sees" the `s/\;/\;\n/;` as having succeeded, so it immediately jumps to the `P;D;` part. This is what outputs

```
N;bA};  # join next line if not a sequence label
```

unmodified.

In summary: `t` makes a difference here not because of its immediate effect of jumping to a label, but because it serves as a dynamic delimiter for the next `t` that gets executed. Without `t` here, the previously executed `s` command is taken into account for the next `t`.

Comment: Beautifully explained! It doesn't seem to be the most intuitive/convenient command to implement, but I guess the creators of sed had good reasons...

Answer (score 1):

#### Part 1 - how the P;D; sequence works.

Compare this two command's outputs: `sed 's/;/;\n/'` and `sed 's/;/;\n/; P;D;'`.

**First:**

```
$ sed 's/;/;\n/' <<< 'one;two;three;four'
one;
two;three;four
```

**Second:**

```
$ sed 's/;/;\n/; P;D;' <<< 'one;two;three;four'
one;
two;
three;
four
```

Why the difference? I will to explain.

The **first** command substitutes only the first occurrence of the `;` character. To substitute all occurrences, the `g` modifier should be added to the `s` command: `sed 's/;/;\n/g'`.

The **second** command works this way:

1. `sed 's/;/;\n/;` - the same as the first command - no difference. Before this command the pattern space is `one;two;three;four`, after - `one\ntwo;three;four`.
2. `P;` -

   - from man: "Print up to the first embedded newline of the current pattern space."
   - That is, it prints up to first newline - `one`. The pattern space stay unchanged: `one\ntwo;three;four`
3. `D;` -

   - from man: "If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle  as  if  the  **d**  command  was
           issued.   Otherwise,  delete  text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart
           cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input."
   - In the our case, pattern space has newline - `one\ntwo;three;four`. The `D;` removes the `one\n` part and repeat all commands cycle from the beginning. Now, the pattern space is:  `two;three;four`.
   - That is, again `sed 's/;/;\n/;` - pattern space: `two\nthree;four`, then `P;` - print `two`, pattern space unchanged: `two\nthree;four`, `D;` - removes `two\n`, pattern space becomes: `three;four`. Etc.

#### Part 2 - what happening with branching.

I looked at the `sed` source code and found next information:

When the `s` command is executing and having match, the `replaced` flag is setting to the true:

```
/* We found a match, set the 'replaced' flag. */
          replaced = true;
```

The `t` command is executing, if the `replaced` flag is true. And it is changing this flag to the `false`:

```
case 't': 
    if (replaced)
    {
        replaced = false;
```

So, in the **first**, `s/\;/\;\n/; t printtopline;` case, the substitution is successful - therefore, `replaced` flag is setting to the true. Then, the following `t` command is running and changing `replaced` flag back to the false.

In the **second** case, without `t` command - `s/\;/\;\n/;`, substitution is successful, too - therefore, `replaced` flag is setting to the true.

But now, this flag is stored to the next cycle, initiated by the `D` command. So, then the first `t` command appears in the new cycle - `s_/^[^/]+/[^;s]*;?_&\n_;      t printtopline`, it checks the `replaced` flag, sees, that the flag is `true` and jumps to the label `:printtopline`, omitting all other commands before the label.

The pattern space doesn't have newlines, so `P;D;` sequence just prints pattern space and starts the next cycle with the new line of input.

Comment: «So, branching to the label doesn't matter here.» Actually my example shows it does, and this is what I would like to understand (leaving out the `P;D` part which I think I got).

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong Yes, I just was carried away by my own example and forgot about your :).

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong I have updated the answer. See the part 2.

Comment: I don't think the source code of one particular sed implementation provides a useful explanation. It doesn't say why `replaced` is used this way, or whether a future version might do things differently. An explanation in terms of the sed language (with references to the documentation) would be better.

Comment: @melpomene I think, both useful in the conjunction. Source code helps to understanding, why it works this way. The main thought is - exists some flag (variable, field, array's element - implementation details doesn't matter here, just entity), which set by the `s` command and unset by the `t` command. In this case, the source code makes it easier to understand, in my opinion.